# API request at the beginning of each minute of the day

Tags: python, loops, time

I am using json.load to make an API request. I'd like to automate it so that it makes the request on the first second of every minute starting at 9:30am and ending at 4pm, ie. 9:30:01am, 9:31:01am ... 4:30:01pm and then stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few different ways todo this but this is probably the easiest to understand, will have to dowbload the pip package first:

```
pip install schedule
```

This is modified from their sample program:

```
import schedule
import time

def job(t):
    print "I'm working...", t
    return

schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(job,'It is 01:00')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```